# Is this the right way to list data from table1 via a key in table 2? (SQL)

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I'm a complete beginner to databases and SQL and I've been smashing my head against the wall for a while with this question. I've tried looking for the answer before posting this but all I could find were more complex questions with answers that didn't really apply to me.
I apologize if by any chance this was already answered and I missed it.

```
Task: list names and last-names of all the workers that work in marketing.

Table1(workers)                                Table2(departments)  

ID    last-name    name    department#         department#     department-name

1     ...          ...          2                   2            marketing
2     ...          ...          5                   5               ...
3     ...          ...          8                   8               ...
4     ...          ...          6                   6               ...
```

This is what I wrote:

```
SELECT name, last-name
FROM workers, departments
WHERE departments.department# = workers.department# AND departments.department-name = "marketing"
```

Is this the correct way to write my query in this instance or is "departments" in the second line of the query redundant since I'm trying to list only names and last-names, which are both in the "workers" table and not "departments".

If it is the right way, is there a better, cleaner way to achieve the same result?

Thank you for your help.

edit: I've done some more reading and I'm curious if this would work, too:

```
SELECT name, last-name
FROM workers
WHERE department# IN
    (SELECT department#
    FROM departments
WHERE department-name LIKE "Marketing%");
```

Appreciate your time.

Comment: mcCrimes shows the standard way to write joins. And to answer your question no it is not redundant. You need to list the table "departments" because your joining the new table. You could however alias departments so you don't have to keep writing out the whole name

Comment: Your edited 2nd option would work, BUT it's worth a couple of notes.  A WHERE IN () approach is usually slower than a JOIN so I'd avoid them typically.  A LIKE match is also going to be slower than an = match, so I wouldn't use one unless you need to.  If you're starting learning about databases, I'd look into JOINs, they're one of the first building blocks for queries and learning about LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN at the very least would give you a good chance of solving most basic queries you might need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest :

```
 SELECT name, last-name
    FROM workers INNER JOIN departments
                 ON workers.department# = departments.department#
    WHERE department-name = 'marketing'
```